custom post type category link does not work
Custom post type category link does not work.
I created new taxonomies in the custom post type, and when I click the link for each category, the page where each category was searched does not appear, but only the same archive page appears.
I thought it was a percaline problem, so I saved it as domain.com/%category%/%postname%/ , but it did not work.
